# Dictionary of Objects where key is an instance field in Java

Tags: java, dictionary

I was wondering if it was possible to have a Java dictionary of objects where one of the fields of the object is defined to be the key of the dictionary.

To be more specific, here's what I would like: I have defined a class with three fields.  One of these fields is an Integer and is unique to each object.  I would like this field to be the key of the dictionary.

Comment: When you insert the object into the dictionary, use that field (or, in this case, it's string equivalent) as the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide the details:

```
public interface HasOwnKey<K> {
    public K getKey();
}

public class MyMap<K, V extends HasOwnKey<K>> {
{
    private Map<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
    public V put(V value) {
    {
        return this.map.put(value.getKey(),value);
    }
    public V get(K key) {
        return this.map.get(key)
    }
    ... etc
}

public class MyClass extends HasOwnKey<String> {
    ...
    @Override String getKey() { return this.key; }
}

MyMap<String, MyClass> myMap = new MyMap<>();
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setKey("abc");
myMap.put(obj);
```

Unfortunately Java 7 doesn't seem to be smart enough to infer `K` from a declaration like

```
public class MyMap<V extends HasOwnKey<K>> {
```

so you have to provide the Key type in two places and cannot do

```
MyMap<MyClass> myMap = new MyMap<>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course it's possible.

Example :

```
Map<Integer,MyClass> map = new HashMap<Integer,MyClass>();
MyClass myObject = new MyClass(...);
map.put (myObject.getIntegerKey(), myObject);
```

Comment: Oh - that makes perfect sense!  In terms of good programming, this solution is okay, right?  My object and all of its fields are immutable.

Comment: @user3892703 It makes perfect sense if the member used as key uniquely identifies the object. It would help you locate instances of this object by their identifier efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily as follows :

```
public class CustomClass 
{
    private int primaryKey;
    private int secondaryField;
    private int tertiaryField;

    public CustomClass(int primaryKey, int secondaryField, int tertiaryField)
    {
        this.primaryKey = primaryKey;
        this.secondaryField = secondaryField;
        this.tertiaryField = tertiaryField;
    }

    public int getPrimaryKey(CustomClass object)
    {
        return object.primaryKey;
    }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CustomClass object = new CustomClass(10, 20, 30);
        Map map = new HashMap<Integer,CustomClass>();
        map.put(object.getPrimaryKey(object), object);
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider using `Enums` for doing the same, if the number of such records is fairly less, as they provide more readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have created a List of those objects you can use an aggregate operation in java 8 like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<MyClass>> theMap = list
                .stream()
                .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(MyClass::myIntegerKey) );
```